# eBay API eBayAuthToken living time

Tags: ebay-api

I have searched in eBay manual and google but could not really find any informaton regarding the lifetime of eBayAuthToken. Is it possible to store the token in my DB instead of username and password? I think it is more secure but the concern is that it may become invalid after a week or so/
Thanks

Comment: Tokens normally exipires in about two years, you can check expiring time on your account information -> https://developer.ebay.com/base/membership/signin/default.aspx

Comment: Oh, thanks. So I suppose it is way safer to store those instead of email/password combination

Answer (score 1):

According to the API docs, the lifespan is 18 months:
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Tokens-About.html#LifeSpanandUniqueness

> Tokens are valid for 18 months across multiple sessions of the application. Seven (7) days before a token is due to expire, eBay returns the expiration date in the HardExpirationWarning field in the response of all calls the application makes on behalf of that user. When your application detects this field, it must redirect the user to the sign-in page on the eBay site by the date in this warning, or the token ceases to work as a means to authenticate that user.